# How to move wordpress website from hosting account to localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I'm getting 404 error while accessing relative paths on 
*Wordpress* website copied from hosting and deployed locally as *Apache* vhost.

Local website is basically *git clone* of the existing remote website.

The following steps were performed to make it work:

- DB urls were searched and replaced using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) to be http://local.webiste.com
- VHost configured according to apache documentation.
- */etc/hosts* modified.

So website can be accessed successfully via http://local.website.com.

Media in *http://local.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017* can be viewed successfully.

Though, accessing a *Wordrpess* page identified by /relative path (relative to current domain/site) causes **"The requested URL /relative/ was not found on this server" error**.

I'm using the same .*htaccess* from the remote *public_html* folder.

How to achive equivalent to hosting behaviour for local vhost website?

Is *.htaccess, apache2* configuration, *vhost* configurations should be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to allow using *.htaccess* in */etc/apache/apache2.conf* by changing from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.
More about it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

So that section related to my local website now looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/local.webiste.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WP Migrate DB](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin to fix URLs and PHP paths, and them you need to fix the `.htaccess` file (PHP path) and maybe `wp-config.php.`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a backup through Wordpress Duplicator/All in one migration plugin

For Duplicator plugin kindly follow that https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

For All in one migration plugin please follow that https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

After backup simply you can create a folder in htdocs folder in xampp then create the database in localhost phymyadmin with same name that you have assign to folder

Then further implementation of the backup you can follow the above links please